# How do I output display at 2560x1080? (am trying to add modeline with xrandr)

Tags: 13.04, resolution, hdmi, intel

I'm trying to use `xrandr` to add a custom resolution for [my 2560x1080 AOC monitor](http://us.aoc.com/monitor_displays/q2963pm).

I've been given the VESA timings by the manufacturer (attached), but I'm not sure what I should be doing with them:

[image: VESA Timings]

I'm using cvt to generate a ModeLine (cvt 2560 1080 60.00), which generates:

```
# 2560x1080 59.98 Hz (CVT) hsync: 67.17 kHz; pclk: 230.00 MHz
#Modeline "2560x1080_60.00" 230.00 2560 2720 2992 3424 1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

I can use `xrandr` to add that Modeline, then add it to HDMI1 - but when I set the monitor to the new resolution, all I'm getting from the monitor is flashing colours, until I drop it back to 1920x1080@60.00.

The laptop I'm using is an Acer Aspire v7-581PG - which has a 720M chip, so using Optimus (I also have bumblebee installed), but it seems that anything being output over HDMI uses the Intel chip anyway (which I believe is a 4400 chipset from the i5)

If I go into nvidia-settings with:

```
# optirun nvidia-settings -c :8,
```

I get to the settings menu, but no monitors are displayed there - so I assume everything's being handled by the Intel chip?).

I know the chipset CAN handle HDMI @ 2560x1080, as Windows 8 had no troubles outputting properly.

I assume I'm doing something wrong with the timings here, but I just can't work out what. I've tried dropping the refresh rate down in decrements of 1, all the way down to 40, but I get the same result - once I get down to 47.00, it just shows a black screen, rather than flashing colours.

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Having a 21:9 monitor running at 1920x1080 is annoying enough to make me consider switching back to windows!

Just to follow up, looking at the VESA timings, the nominal frequency is 181.250, so I have tried the following but get the same issue:

```
#Modeline "2560x1080_60.00" 230.00 2560 2720 2992 3424 1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Comment: Just to follow up, looking at the VESA timings, the nominal frequency is 181.250, so I have tried #Modeline "2560x1080_60.00" 230.00 2560 2720 2992 3424 1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync but get the same issue

Comment: I have same problem with lg-25UM65-P (21:9 inches). it works great on windows 8.1 and has output of 2560 * 1080 automatically over HDMI (which some think that's the problem which is not!).
but i searched a lot and got nothing about Ubuntu and my nvidia GEFORCE 610M-2GB.

Answer (score 2):

I have connected ultrawide monitor by HDMI with

```
Modeline "2560x1080_40.00"  147.25  2560 2680 2944 3328  1080 1083 1093 1108 -hsync +vsync
```

I used:

```
cvt 2560 1080 40
```

[HDMI did not support > 165 Mhz](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/545958/linux/21-9-aspect-ratio-supported-or-not-on-gt640-card-/post/3830451/#3830451), however HDMI 1.3 supports up to 340 MHz maximum pixel clock rate [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI).

Comment: Where and how did you add this modeline?