# ubuntu 18.4.3 + LG 25" 25UM58-P (ultrawide 21:9 2560x1080)

Tags: dell, intel-graphics, display-resolution, lg

I have a problem with my new LG 21:9 monitor. I can't add 2560 x 1080 resolution.

PC Dell Optiplex 7010, integrated Intel HD Graphics 2500 + LG 25" 25UM58-P monitor.

I've just found a nice code here [script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978410/ubuntu-16-04-3-lts-lg-29um58-p-ultrawide-219-2560x1080) I changed it a little for my needs:

```
gtf 2560 1080 50
# 2560x1080 @ 50.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 55.60 kHz; pclk: 188.60 MHz
  Modeline "2560x1080_50.00"  188.60  2560 2704 2976 3392  1080 1081 1084 1112  -HSync +Vsync
 xrandr --newmode "TEST" 188.60  2560 2704 2976 3392  1080 1081 1084 1112  -HSync +Vsync
 xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 "TEST"
 xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode "TEST"
```

And when I run it in terminal it works perfectly.

Then I created file .xprofile and saved it:

sudo gedit ~/.xprofile

```
#!/bin/sh
MODE_NAME="ULTRAWIDE"
OUTPUT="HDMI-1"
CONNECTED_OUTPUT=$(xrandr --current | grep -i $OUTPUT | cut -f2 -d' ')

if [ "$CONNECTED_OUTPUT" == "connected" ];
then
# SET 2560x1080 50 HZ
xrandr --newmode "$MODE_NAME" 188.60  2560 2704 2976 3392  1080 1081 1084 1112  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 "$MODE_NAME"
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode "$MODE_NAME"
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --primary
else
   echo "ULTRAWIDE IS NOT DETECTED !"
fi
```

but there's an error:

[** (gedit:11640): WARNING **: 15:20:09.130: Set document metadata failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYGSZ.png)

[sudo] user password tomasz:

** (gedit: 11640): WARNING **: 15: 20: 09.130: Set document metadata failed: Setting the metadata attribute :: gedit-spell-language is not supported

And after rebooting the new resolution 2560 x 1080 didn't work.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. After one of the last upgrade I can change resolution to 2560 x 1080 ... in Settings. As simple as that :) Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do the `gedit ~/.xprofile` command - without `sudo` ? 
It worked for me, on Ubuntu 14.04, with i915 chipset graphics on SyncMaster 765MB - but with `.xprofile` in my regular user homedir - my added resolution is `1152x864` with 75 Hz refresh rate ....

Comment: When I do "gedit ~/.xprofile" comand without "sudo" I can open the file as read-only.

Answer (score -1):

Here you can find a nice solution https://medium.com/@AbhiXpert/add-change-the-custom-resolution-of-your-display-using-xrandr-on-ubuntu-18-04-in-a-minute-338caec6e29