# External monitors resolution and ratio are not detected correctly

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xrandr

Ubuntu 16.04 is not detecting the correct resolution/ratio of my external 34"-screen which is connected via HDMI to my notebook.

Detected resolution: 3840 x 2160 (16:9); desired resolution: 3440 x 1440 (21:9).

I followed [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727753/how-do-i-configure-ubuntu-for-a-219-screen), but it's not working and I don't know why. I don't see an error message. Where is the log-file located?

What I did:

```
cvt 3440 1440 60
xrandr --newmode "3440x1440_60.00"  419.50  3440 3696 4064 4688  1440 1443 1453 1493 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DP-1 "3440x1440_60.00"
xrandr --output DP-1 --mode "3440x1440_60.00"
```

I downloaded the xrandr GUI `ARandR` where I can select the new mode, but then the screen goes black, it switches back to the default screen (notebook) and after a few seconds I'm back where I started (16:9).

Edit:
I works perfectly with 30hz, but the screen is supposed to support 75hz which doesn't work either.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, could you add the output of script https://askubuntu.com/a/727897/26246 to the question.