# Set resolution 2560x1080 Wayland update 21.04

Tags: grub2, display, display-resolution, wayland

I recently updated from Ubuntu 20.04 Groovy Gorilla to **Ubuntu 21.04 hirsute**. With 20.04 I was able to set the custom resolution of my LG ULTRAWIDE monitor to 2560x1080 using **xrandr** because my session type was **Xorg**. The 21.04 update was not successful but that is a seperate case. Once I fixed the botched update issue, I logged in and certain things were missing and uninstalled but most importantly the resolution problem.

Using `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` I was able to see that my session type had changed to **wayland**.

And the connected displays were the following using `xrandr -q | grep connected`
[image]
Essentially XWAYLAND1 is my ULTRAWIDE Display

I used `for p in /sys/class/drm/*/status; do con=${p%/status}; echo -n "${con#*/card?-}: "; cat $p; done` as an alternative way to getting the display types for the attempts below
[image]
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Kernel_mode_setting

**Attempts made:**

1. Update resolution using `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and change the **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT** to the following.
   [image]
   Original was: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor". Then commit to that change with `sudo update-grub`
2. Using Grub Customizer instead as an alternative method.
   [image]
3. Using a script created in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`
   [image]

**Reasons behind attempts**

4. Method 1 and 2 was: [custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-wayland](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/05/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-wayland-xorg/)
5. Method 3 was: [How do I configure Ubuntu for a 21:9 screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727753/how-do-i-configure-ubuntu-for-a-219-screen/819253#819253)

**What failed**

6. Apparently using grub.

> You can’t set custom resolution higher than the maximum one in
> Display settings

[image]

7. The script was intended to add those settings upon boot from my understanding, but nothing is happening.

**References**

- [wiki.debian.org/Wayland](https://wiki.debian.org/Wayland)
- [wiki.archlinux.org/title/Wayland#Configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Wayland#Configuration)
- [wiki.archlinux.org/title/GDM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GDM)
- [enabling-resolutions](https://samuelmartin.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/enabling-resolutions-in-ubuntu-12-04-lubuntu-12-04/)
- [wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#By_Session_with_.xprofile](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#By_Session_with_.xprofile)

Lastly logging out does not present the option to change settings from wayland to xorg

Comment: Are you saying there is no options icon/menu in far bottom-right of 21.04 logon screen to change from the default Wayland? Like this screenshot: https://technowikis.com/sites/technowikis.com/uploads/071/7146143206980096844.png I know the options icon used to be right next to the password field in older versions so it's now easily missed if you don't know it's there.

Comment: The icon is there after I disabled Wayland [Disable Wayland](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-20-04-desktop). But that is still a terrible solution so I have read.